# Model residuals are normally distributed but they are heteroscedastic and autocorrelated

Tags: linear-model, heteroscedasticity, normality-assumption, durbin-watson-test, breusch-pagan

I have a candidate set of five linear models, as I want to choose the model with the lowest AIC and calculate predictions from it. For each model, I have tested for normality of model residuals (`shapiro.test(residuals(model))` from `stats` R package), homoscedasticity of model residuals (`bptest(model)` from `lmtest` R package) and autocorrelation of model residuals (`durbinWatsonTest(model)` from `car` R package).

The model residuals of the five models are normally distributed, but the homoscedasticity and autocorrelation tests are significant for all models, indicating that model residuals are heteroscedastic and autocorrelated.

As model residuals are normally distributed, is the violation of homoscedasticity and non-correlation of model residuals important in my case? Can I still go ahead with my model selection and calculation of predictions, or is there something wrong with my models?

Comment: Various other issues aside, if the residuals are heteroskedastic, the test you're using for marginal normality is not relevant, since the residuals come from different distributions; the mixture you get for the marginal distribution may be very different from the conditional distribution.